# Are there permanently mounted bike computers?

Tags: bike-computer

Over the years I've owned multiple bike computers (whose things that tell your speed/distance). Each time the head either falls off while I'm riding or I remove it, but lose it somewhere.

I want my next purchase to be one that is permanently affixed to my handlebars so that it never falls off or gets lost. I'm looking for one with strong mounting mechanism. I want to have to get out a screwdriver to replace the battery. I can't seem to find any one on the market that does this. Any help?

Comment: A little short sighted IMO - I think you'll become a magnet for thieves or vandals.   How about something like a wahoo rflkt that talks to a cellphone?  http://au.wahoofitness.com/devices/rflkt.html  Plus the mount looks better and more sturdy.

Comment: I've only once had one fall off while riding, and it was a case of good riddance.  But if you felt you must you could easily glue most units in place on their mounts (at least until you needed to change the battery).

Comment: I've had a Shimano "Flight Deck" computer on my bike for just about 10 years now. It's never unclipped itself from the mount (and doing so seems quite unlikely since it snaps in securely), but ironically, the screw worked itself loose and the entire mount came loose (but I didn't lose the bike computer since it was held onto the bike by the wires).   I don't see how it could be any more secure... sure, I could unclip it myself and lose it or it could be stolen, but the same is true with a screw-on mount since I might want to remove it or someone might snap it off.

Comment: I dimly recall a bike computer which could be fixed in place with a small screw so that it counts towards bicycle weight in competitions (i.e. instead of your 6.8kg road bike + computer you have a 6.7kg road bike + fixed ~100g computer). But I think it was one of the more expensive units with GNSS and recording capabilities.

Comment: @Michael You're thinking of Wahoo computers, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

> To err is human, but to really foul things up you need a computer.
>
> Paul R. Ehrlich

The best computer, is no computer at all! I am sure I will take flack for this, but if all you are interested in is speed and distance, why not go with an old style bike speedometer.  Permanent mounting and no batteries.  Just watch out for the roaming bands of bike hipster thieves, they may steal your whole bike to get at the speedometer.

[image]

Comment: I had one of these as kid, and it really, really sucked until it broke after a few weeks. My parents didn't want to buy me one, I guess they knew something I didn't at the time.

Answer (score 4):

I would look for a way to improve your existing mount interface to make it less prone to falling off rather than making it permanent.  Adding bits of rubber, sticky back stuff, or possibly even hook and loop tape to keep things in place better.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Excellent point, additional details would be good.

Answer (score 3):

VDO m-zero mounts permanently (cable ties).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of extending your answer with a couple of photos to show that this model appears to have no separate socket-mount.  Good find and welcome!  I suggest you browse the [tour] to see how this site is organised, and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer can help form a longer answer too.

Comment: Nice answer, do you use this computer?  Since the question talks about changing the battery, it might be nice if you could add details about how that is done.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is a little late to the party, but it is worthwhile to note that there were computer (oedometer, to be precise) that are installed directly into the stem:

[image: detailed view]
[image: side view]

They are out of production, but who knows, maybe the mold are still in some drawer in some far-east manufacturing site and they will reappear soon...

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen one since those old school mechanical odometers that attach to the front axle. I think your best bet is to add a small screw to the mount to lock the computer in place.

If you get something small and pointy like this one, less than 1.5mm across the shaft, you should be able to screw it straight into the mount so that the point hits the computer. I suspect you could do this without drilling a hole first, but I would drill the hole.

[image: small screw]

If you're lucky the mount will look like this one and you'll be able to put the screw vertically up underneath through non-critical plastic. That way if you do crack it it doesn't matter too much.

[image]

It might be worth buying one that has spare mounts available on eBay, and buying a couple of spares. Then you could just superglue the speedo into the mount and cut it out when the battery needs replacing.

Answer (score 2):

That screw seems the worst of all possible choices. I can't imagine a way that compromising either the waterproofing or the electronics doesn't seem likely. If it has to be permanently mounted, glue it into the out-front style mount and glue the tightening bolt into the mount. I have no idea how you'd charge it given it would make it hard to access the charging ports but there you go.

That said, I've never had a Garmin fall off be it in a crash or just riding along with the out front mounts. Given it seems what your main problem is that you can't stop losing bike computers I'd recommend that you use a current generation 520 or higher and take advantage of the wireless sync (either wifi or over your phone data) then never take the Garmin off the bike except for charging.

Comment: Would you lock the bike it in a public bike rack with this attached?  I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

**No, there are no permanently mounted bike computers.**

To slightly misquote what [Rider_X has said](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/35642/8273) the best computer is no computer.

Computers are a tyranny that should be resisted.

[Velominati](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/) has plenty to say on this topic

- [Rule #68](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#68)
  *Rides are to be measured by quality, not quantity.*
- [Rule #6](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#6)
  *Free your mind and your legs will follow.*
- [Rule #74](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#74) *V Meters or small computers only* (note that the aforementioned V Meter is a fictional product).
- Not to mention [Rule #5](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#6). (I did say not to mention it).

However, if you want to log rides and distances for historical value, you could use a smartphone app, such as [Strava](https://www.strava.com/), [Endemondo](https://www.endomondo.com/), [Map My Ride](http://www.mapmyride.com/), etc.

Comment: I have to object.  For the tourist some sort of odometer is essential, and relying on a smartphone to do the job is distracting, inaccurate, and unreliable.  (Not to mention that you're riding the bike to get away from the damned phone.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks Ah the usual DRH down vote, from the most down voting user on [bicycles.se]. Do you have any sense of community? Or fun? The answer, I'm afraid is obvious to all.

Comment: And, I might say, I did *not* say not to use an odometer.

Comment: The OP asked about a unit to tell speed/distance -- essentially an odometer.  You offered no suggestions to fill that need or explain why it wasn't really needed.  Hence your "answer" was "not useful".  Read the hover text on the downvote button.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Read the headline question. The answer is *no*. But you don't answer the questions I asked you. I'm coming to think if I don't get a -1 from you, then there's something wrong.

Comment: A small wireless bike computer also works when it sits in you jersey pocket, preferably the small zipped one!

Comment: @Carel Excellent point!